# Setting Selected Image in Tab Bar Controller with Storyboard ios7

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I am using Storyboarding and I have a tab bar controller with 3 tabs. I am able to set the image for the tab bar item. 
I am not able to figure out how I can do this using storyboard.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [John Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;

UITabBarItem *targetTabBarItem = [[tabbar items] objectAtIndex:0]; // whichever tab-item
UIImage *selectedIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name-of-selected-image.png"];
[targetTabBarItem setSelectedImage:selectedIcon];
```